# Roaming profile location not updating

Tags: windows-8, roaming-profiles

We have roaming profiles enabled for some users. We want to move some of them over to a new network share.

We have copied the files to the location (using Windows backup so that permissions are retained) and we've changed the location in active directory (see screenshot 1). When the user logs in to windows 8 their documents folders still points to the old server (server names removed from the picture but you can see the path is different).

[image]
[image]

The user has logged off and logged back on, and has also run GP update (followed by a shutdown/restart)

What do I need to do to make Windows 8 recognise the change?